# Rails 4 link tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to make an app with Rails 4.

I have a projects model and profiles model.

My objective is to make the name of the project creator a link to the profile page of the user who made the project.

In my projects view, I have:

```
<%= link_to '
          <%= @creator_profile.title %> <%= "#{@creator.first_name}  #{@creator.last_name}" %>
          ', @creator_profile_path %> </span>
```

In my projects controller, I have defined creator as the user who creates the project (so the link doesnt go to the user profile that is logged in):

```
 def show
    #authorise @project

    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @creator = User.find(@project.creator_id)
    @creator_profile = @creator.profile
 end
```

My attempt is incorrect, but I can't figure out how to link these. Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= link_to "#{@creator_profile.title} #{@creator.first_name} #{@creator.last_name}", @creator_profile %>
```

You just want one string interpolation.  You don't need the extra erb tags as you already have them on the link_to.  The alternative way would be to pass a block to link_to

```
<%= link_to @creator_profile do %>
  <%= "#{@creator_profile.title} #{@creator.first_name} #{@creator.last_name}" %>
<% end %>
```

I assume you have routes setup so that rails can correctly "guess" the profile link based of the profile object.